# Layout changed when I don't have any other keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, layout, dvorak

I have just one keyboard layout and that is English(Dvorak) but pressing Alt+LeftShift still changed the keyboard layout to QWERTY ! How can I solve this problem? (in ubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 0):

You can access Text Entry Setting from Dash.

Comment: I set only one keyboard layout in settings. but pressing Alt+LeftShift still changes the layout to QWERTY.